# Automatically Backup Sqlserver 2012 database weekly

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2012

Currently I have a code for backing up my database but I would like to know how I can do this automatically every week/ month.

I am using sql server 2012.

.aspx

```
 <asp:Button ID="Button111" runat="server" OnClick="Button111_Click" Text="backup" CssClass="btn btn-success btn-lg" />  <asp:Label ID="lblError" runat="server" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
```

.aspx.cs

```
protected void Button111_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mycon"].ToString());

    string backupDIR = "C:\\backup";
    if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(backupDIR))
    {
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(backupDIR);
    }
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("backup database iporma to disk= '" + backupDIR + "\\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyy_HHss") + ".Bak'", con);
        sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        lblError.Text = "Completed";


    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblError.Text = "Error" + ex.ToString();
    }

}
```

please go easy on me,

thanks

Comment: Why don't you use a SQL Server Agent job? And/or create a maintenance plan? Why are you trying to do this from a *web site*?

Comment: you can create a timer that runs every week/ month etc. Or use  SQL Server agent job

Comment: @styx no you can't. You can't do that even with *desktop* services and expect any kind of reliability

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos why not?

Comment: @styx consider the lifetime of the request and even the application pool itself. Local objects are gc'd when the request ends. Even a global timer object gets killed when the application pool recycles. Besides, services *crash*. You can't depend on in-memory objects for this. Which is why scheduling services don't depend on timers for scheduling.

Comment: Isn't this actually an infrastructure administration question? (Which would be OT)?

Comment: @Fildor almost but not quite. There *are* cases where you'd want a web site to control such things, eg for multi-tenant scenarios, or for self-service dashboards. The question is far too vague though. Why use Hangfire instead of SQL Server Agent for example? Is it that the OP doesn't know about SQL Server administration? Or there are missing requirements?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks for the details answer

Comment: @styx SQL Server *already* has the Agent service to run jobs. Windows itself *already* has the Task Scheduling service. There are cases where these aren't enough though, in which case Hangfire and Quartz.net are libraries that implement scheduling. If you check how they work you'll see that it's a lot more complicated than running something every N minutes

Comment: @styx never mind having *multiple servers*, a common scenario in the microservices era.

Comment: Sorry for the really late reply i have figured out how to use sql server maintenance and job to setup the weekly backup but can It be possible to do that within my code? like not in SSMS